# Phone number formatting on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, phone-number, number-formatting

I have a text field where the user enters data. It's a phone number field. If the user enters `1234567890`, I want it displayed as `(123)-(456)-7890` as the user types. How is this possible?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

This will help you

Format (xxx) xxx-xxxx

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    int length = (int)[self getLength:textField.text];
    //NSLog(@"Length  =  %d ",length);

    if(length == 10)
    {
        if(range.length == 0)
            return NO;
    }

    if(length == 3)
    {
        NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];

        if(range.length > 0)
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];
    }
    else if(length == 6)
    {
        NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
        //NSLog(@"%@",[num  substringToIndex:3]);
        //NSLog(@"%@",[num substringFromIndex:3]);
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];

        if(range.length > 0)
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (NSString *)formatNumber:(NSString *)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

    int length = (int)[mobileNumber length];
    if(length > 10)
    {
        mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];
        NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

    }

    return mobileNumber;
}

- (int)getLength:(NSString *)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    int length = (int)[mobileNumber length];

    return length;
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much. It worked perfectly as I wanted. This will help beginners like me a lot.

Comment: I Used your code. but how will i mention, which textfield it is. I have the textfield inside the custom UITableviewcell.  Please look at my edit.

Comment: Set a tag for the textfield in which you want to format the phone number and ignore the other textfield based on the tag values

Comment: it will not work if you select and delete a piece of the telephone number

Comment: "Set a tag for the textfield in which you want to format the phone number and ignore the other textfield based on the tag values"  Can you explain the tag for me?  my TextField is called phoneField.  Thanks

Comment: This may work for a quick and dirty solution, but lacks a lot of support that I wish to have. It doesn't work for international numbers, it doesn't work for numbers longer than 10 digits, it doesn't format numbers when deleting characters or editing characters.

Answer (score 43):

This felt more clear and handles removing any unwanted characters much more nicely. Formats correctly for **1 (###) ###‑####** or **(###) ###‑####**

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSArray *components = [newString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
    NSString *decimalString = [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    NSUInteger length = decimalString.length;
    BOOL hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && [decimalString characterAtIndex:0] == '1';

    if (length == 0 || (length > 10 && !hasLeadingOne) || (length > 11)) {
        textField.text = decimalString;
        return NO;
    }

    NSUInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableString *formattedString = [NSMutableString string];

    if (hasLeadingOne) {
        [formattedString appendString:@"1 "];
        index += 1;
    }

    if (length - index > 3) {
        NSString *areaCode = [decimalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 3)];
        [formattedString appendFormat:@"(%@) ",areaCode];
        index += 3;
    }

    if (length - index > 3) {
        NSString *prefix = [decimalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 3)];
        [formattedString appendFormat:@"%@-",prefix];
        index += 3;
    }

    NSString *remainder = [decimalString substringFromIndex:index];
    [formattedString appendString:remainder];

    textField.text = formattedString;

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Best solution out there for related questions, should be upvoted much much more.

Comment: Thank you. I did use a modified version of this for xxx-xxx-xxxx format.

Comment: I would suggest also adding tags to all phone number text fields and doing this to get rid of leading 1's if the rest of the number is deleted -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{ if(textField.tag == 99){
        if([textField.text isEqualToString:@"1 "]){
            textField.text = nil;
        } }

Comment: Or
Fix the problem like this:
BOOL hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && [decimalString characterAtIndex:0] == '1';
        
if(textField.text.length == 2 && length)
return YES;
        
if (length == 0 || (length > 10 && !hasLeadingOne) || (length > 11)) {
   textField.text = decimalString;
   return NO;
}

Comment: One more comment in use - if you have few textFields - don't forget to check which you are validating with `textField.tag`

Answer (score 16):

The code bellow is what I typically use. The format is different but you get the picture. This will handle input such as '123df#$@$gdfg45-+678dfg901' and output '1 (234) 567-8901'

```
#import "NSString+phoneNumber.h"

@implementation NSString (phoneNumber)

-(NSString*) phoneNumber{
    static NSCharacterSet* set = nil;
    if (set == nil){
        set = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    }
    NSString* phoneString = [[self componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    switch (phoneString.length) {
        case 7: return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@", [phoneString substringToIndex:3], [phoneString substringFromIndex:3]];
        case 10: return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-%@", [phoneString substringToIndex:3], [phoneString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 3)],[phoneString substringFromIndex:6]];
        case 11: return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@) %@-%@", [phoneString substringToIndex:1], [phoneString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 3)], [phoneString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 3)], [phoneString substringFromIndex:7]];
        case 12: return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%@ (%@) %@-%@", [phoneString substringToIndex:2], [phoneString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 3)], [phoneString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 3)], [phoneString substringFromIndex:8]];
        default: return nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: It'd be better to return PhoneNumberString in default case if the length is below seven.

Answer (score 10):

We wrote a custom NSFormatter subclass for phone numbers here: https://github.com/edgecase/PhoneNumberFormatter

You can use it like any other NSFormatter subclass.

Comment: Is this format general ???
and I'm just add .h/.m file to my project need something more ??

Answer (score 6):

Thanks so much for the first answer but, i think, that method `-(int)getLength:(NSString*)mobileNumber` is useless. You can try something like below:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

int length = [[self formatNumber:[textField text]] length];

if (length == 10) {
    if(range.length == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
}

if (length == 3) {
    NSString *num = [self formatNumber:[textField text]];
    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];
    if (range.length > 0) {
        [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]]];
    }
}
else if (length == 6) {
    NSString *num = [self formatNumber:[textField text]];
    [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]]];
    if (range.length > 0) {
        [textField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]]];
    }
}

return YES;
}

- (NSString*)formatNumber:(NSString*)mobileNumber {
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

int length = [mobileNumber length];

if (length > 10) {
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];
}

return mobileNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who require international number formatting: https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comes with C++, Java and JavaScript implementations.  Should be easy to wrap the C++ implementations in a .mm file and write a small Objective-C wrapper around it.

Comment: I tried this and got it working. Unfortunately, the C++ library is ~2 MB and it needs ~40 MB worth of dependency libraries. The largest dependency is the International Components for Unicode library which is about 35 MB by itself because it includes "a standard library of data that is about 16 MB in size. Most of this consists of conversion tables and locale information." So this solution is not very practical for an iOS app.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use this simple method:

```
+ (NSString*) formatPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber codeLength:(int) code segmentLength:(int) segment
{
    NSString* result = @"";

    int length = [phoneNumber length];

    NSString* firstSegment = @"";
    NSString* restSegment = @"";

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {

        char c = [phoneNumber characterAtIndex:i];

        if(i < code)
            firstSegment = [firstSegment stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c", c];
        else
        {
            restSegment = [restSegment stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c", c];

            int threshold = (i - code) + 1;

            if((threshold % segment == 0) && (threshold > 0) && !(threshold > length))
                restSegment = [restSegment stringByAppendingFormat:@"%c", '-'];
        }

    }

    result = [result stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@-%@", firstSegment, restSegment];

    return result;
}
```

Assuming above method is in `Contact` class, just use the method like this:

```
NSString* phoneNumber = @"085755023455";

NSString* formattedNumber = [Contact formatPhoneNumber:phoneNumber codeLength:3 segmentLength:4];
```

That would be resulting something like:

```
085-7550-2345-5
```

Answer (score 2):

A valid option is https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS
All the other answer cover only a small part of the possibilities and combinations, this library actually parse and validate EVERY phone number, and identify:

- Nationality
- phone number type
- National carrier

Answer (score 2):

**Relevant for U.S. Phone Numbers:**

Adding to @wan's post, I added a conditional statement if the user starts with the country code (1). That way, it will format to be: 1 (XXX) XXX-XXXX instead of (1XX) XXX-XXXX.

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    textField = self.phoneNumberTextField;

    NSInteger length = [self getLength:textField.text];
    //NSLog(@"Length  =  %d ",length);

    if ([textField.text hasPrefix:@"1"]) {
        if(length == 11)
        {
            if(range.length == 0)
                return NO;
        }
        if(length == 4)
        {
            NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@) ",[num substringToIndex:1],[num substringFromIndex:1]];
            if(range.length > 0)
                textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:4]];
        }
        else if(length == 7)
        {
            NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
            NSRange numRange = NSMakeRange(1, 3);
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@) %@-",[num substringToIndex:1] ,[num substringWithRange:numRange],[num substringFromIndex:4]];
            if(range.length > 0)
                textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
        }

    } else {
        if(length == 10)
        {
            if(range.length == 0)
                return NO;
        }

        if(length == 3)
        {
            NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];
            if(range.length > 0)
                textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];
        }
        else if(length == 6)
        {
            NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];

            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num  substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
            if(range.length > 0)
                textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

-(NSString*)formatNumber:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

    NSInteger length = [mobileNumber length];
    if(length > 10)
    {
        mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];
        NSLog(@"%@", mobileNumber);

    }


    return mobileNumber;
}
-(NSInteger)getLength:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{

    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

    NSInteger length = [mobileNumber length];

    return length;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AKNumericFormatter](https://github.com/blackm00n/AKNumericFormatter)library for it. It has formatter and convenient UITextField category, it's available as a cocoapod.

Answer (score 1):

C# Xamarin.iOS version of [most comprehensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14558678/883738) on how to do phone formatting in iOS is below

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        PhoneNumberTextField.ShouldChangeCharacters = ChangeCharacters;
    }

    private bool ChangeCharacters(UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString)
    {
        var text = textField.Text;
        var newString = text.Substring(0, range.Location) + replacementString + text.Substring(range.Location + range.Length);
        var decimalString = Regex.Replace(newString, @"[^\d]", string.Empty);
        var length = decimalString.Length;
        var hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && decimalString[0] == '1';
        if ((length == 0) || (length > 10 && !hasLeadingOne) || (length > 11))
        {
            textField.Text = decimalString;
            return false;
        }
        var index = 0;
        var formattedString = "";
        if (hasLeadingOne)
        {
            formattedString += "1";
            index += 1;
        }
        if (length - index > 3)
        {
            var areaCode = decimalString.Substring(index, 3);
            formattedString += "(" + areaCode + ")";
            index += 3;
        }
        if (length - index > 3)
        {
            var prefix = decimalString.Substring(index, 3);
            formattedString += " " + prefix + "-";
            index += 3;
        }
        var remainder = decimalString.Substring(index);
        formattedString += remainder;
        textField.Text = formattedString;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Also for format **+x (xxx) xxx-xx-xx** you can use something like this simple solution:

```
+ (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
NSArray *components = [newString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
NSString *decimalString = [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];

if (decimalString.length > 11) {
    return NO;
}

NSMutableString *formattedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:decimalString];

[formattedString insertString:@"+" atIndex:0];

if (formattedString.length > 2)
    [formattedString insertString:@" (" atIndex:2];

if (formattedString.length > 7)
    [formattedString insertString:@") " atIndex:7];

if (formattedString.length > 12)
    [formattedString insertString:@"-" atIndex:12];

if (formattedString.length > 15)
    [formattedString insertString:@"-" atIndex:15];


textField.text = formattedString;
return NO;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## SWIFT

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {        
            let length = self.getTextLength(textField.text)
            
            
            
            if length == 10{
                if range.length == 0{
                    return false
                }
            }
            
            if length == 3{
                
                var num : String = self.formatNumber(textField.text)
                
                textField.text = num + "-"
                if(range.length > 0){
                    textField.text = (num as NSString).substringToIndex(3)
                }
            }
            else if length == 6{
                
                var num : String = self.formatNumber(textField.text)
                
                let prefix  = (num as NSString).substringToIndex(3)
                let postfix = (num as NSString).substringFromIndex(3)
                
                textField.text = prefix + "-" + postfix + "-"
                
                if range.length > 0{
                    textField.text = prefix + postfix
                }
            }
            
            return true
    }




func getTextLength(mobileNo: String) -> NSInteger{
        
        var str : NSString = mobileNo as NSString
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString: "")
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "")
        
        return str.length
    }
    
    func formatNumber(mobileNo: String) -> String{
        var str : NSString = mobileNo as NSString
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString: "")
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("-", withString: "")
        str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "")
        
        if str.length > 10{
            str = str.substringFromIndex(str.length - 10)
        }

        return str as String
    }
```

Comment: it displaying xxx-xx-xxxx and question is asked for (xxx)-(xxx)-xxxx

Answer (score 1):

#### Swift Formatted Phone Number

Improves oppon @datinc's answer,
input such as `1123df#$@$gdfg45-+678dfg901` will be output as `+11(234)567-8901`

```
func formattedPhone(phone: String) -> String?  {
    let notPhoneNumbers = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
    let str = phone.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(notPhoneNumbers).joinWithSeparator("")

    let startIdx = str.startIndex
    let endIdx = str.endIndex

    let count = str.characters.count
    if count == 7 {
        return "\(str[startIdx..<startIdx.advancedBy(3)])-\(str[startIdx.advancedBy(3)..<endIdx])"
    }else if count == 10{
        return "(\(str[startIdx..<startIdx.advancedBy(3)]))\(str[startIdx.advancedBy(3)..<startIdx.advancedBy(6)])-\(str[startIdx.advancedBy(6)..<endIdx])"
    }
    else if count > 10{
        let extra = str.characters.count - 10
        return "+\(str[startIdx..<startIdx.advancedBy(extra)])(\(str[endIdx.advancedBy(-10)..<endIdx.advancedBy(-7)]))\(str[endIdx.advancedBy(-7)..<endIdx.advancedBy(-4)])-\(str[endIdx.advancedBy(-4)..<endIdx])"
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

Format (xxx) xxx-xxxx For **SWIFT 3.0**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let length = Int(getLength(mobileNumber: textField.text!))

        if length == 15 {
            if range.length == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }

        if length == 3 {

            let num = self.formatNumber(mobileNumber: textField.text!)

            textField.text = NSString(format:"(%@)",num) as String

            if range.length > 0{
                let index: String.Index = num.index(num.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
                textField.text = NSString(format:"%@",num.substring(to: index)) as String
            }

        }else if length == 6 {
            let num = self.formatNumber(mobileNumber: textField.text!)
            let index: String.Index = num.index(num.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)

            textField.text = NSString(format:"(%@) %@-",num.substring(to: index), num.substring(from: index)) as String
            if range.length > 0{
                textField.text = NSString(format:"(%@) %@",num.substring(to: index), num.substring(from: index)) as String
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    func formatNumber(mobileNumber: String) -> String {
        var number = mobileNumber
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "")

        let length = Int(number.characters.count)

        if length > 15 {
            let index = number.index(number.startIndex, offsetBy: 15)

           number = number.substring(to: index)
        }

        return number
    }

    func getLength(mobileNumber: String) -> Int {

        var number = mobileNumber
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: ")", with: "")
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        number = number.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "")

        let length = Int(number.characters.count)
        return length

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str=@"[+]+91[0-9]{10}";
NSPredicate *no=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",str];
if([no evaluateWithObject:txtMobileno.text]==NO
{ 
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Please Enter correct contact no." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this method will format for (xxx) xxx - xxxx ....

it is a modification of the current top answer and handles backspaces

```
- (IBAction)autoFormat:(UITextField *)sender {

NSString *mobileNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sender.text];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];

int length = [mobileNumber length];
if(length > 0 && [sender.text length] > self.oldLength){
    if(length >= 7 && length <= 10){
        sender.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@ - %@",[mobileNumber substringToIndex:3], [mobileNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,3)],[mobileNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(6,[mobileNumber length]-6)]];
    } else if(length >= 4 && length <= 6) {
        sender.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[mobileNumber substringToIndex:3], [mobileNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,[mobileNumber length]-3)]];
    }
    if(length >= 11 && length % 4 == 3){
        NSString *lastChar = [sender.text substringFromIndex:[sender.text length] - 1];
        sender.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[sender.text substringToIndex:[sender.text length] - 1],lastChar];
    }
    self.oldLength = [sender.text length];
} else if([sender.text length] < self.oldLength) {
    NSLog(@"deleted - ");
    self.oldLength = 0;

    sender.text = @"";
    for (int i = 0; i < [mobileNumber length]; i = i + 1) {
        sender.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",sender.text,[mobileNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
        [self autoFormat:sender];
    }
}}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

[REFormattedNumberField](https://github.com/romaonthego/REFormattedNumberField) is probably the best. Just supply a format you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSString *) phoneNumberFormatterTextField:(NSString *)number forRange:(NSRange)range
{
    int length = (int)[[self getPhoneNumber:number] length];
    if(length == 3)
    {
        NSString *num = [MPosBaseScreenController getPhoneNumber:number];
        number = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(\\d{3})"
                                              withString:@"($1) "
                                                 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, num.length)];

    }
    else if(length == 6 || length > 6 )
    {
        NSString *num = [MPosBaseScreenController getPhoneNumber:number];
        number = [num stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(\\d{3})(\\d{3})"
                                              withString:@"($1) $2 - "
                                                 options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, num.length)];
    }
       return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple category which will mimic the format of the input

```
@interface NSString (formatDecimalsAs)
- (NSString *)formatDecimalsAs:(NSString *)formattedDecimals;
@end

@implementation NSString (formatDecimalsAs)
- (NSString *)formatDecimalsAs:(NSString *)formattedDecimals
{
    // insert non-digit characters from source string
    NSMutableString *formattedNumber = [self mutableCopy];
    for (int i = 0; i < formattedDecimals.length; i++)
    {
        if (i > formattedNumber.length)
        {
            break;
        }
        unichar character = [formattedDecimals characterAtIndex:i];
        if ([[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet].invertedSet characterIsMember:character])
        {
            [formattedNumber insertString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", character] atIndex:(NSUInteger) i];
        }
    }
    return formattedNumber;
}
@end
```

example use

```
[@"87654321" formatDecimalsAs:@"1111 1111"] // returns @"8765 4321"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Removes all non-digit characters
2. If 7 digits remain, 123-4567
3. for 10 digits, (123) 456-7890
4. Otherwise, groups of three. To adjust the size of the groups, change the value assigned to substrsize

   ```
   -(NSString*)formatPhone:(NSString*)phone {

        NSString *formattedNumber = [[phone componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                             [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]]
                            componentsJoinedByString:@""];

   int substrSize = 3;
   NSMutableArray *t = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:formattedNumber.length / substrSize + 1];
   switch (formattedNumber.length) {
       case 7:
           formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",
                          [formattedNumber substringToIndex:3],
                          [formattedNumber substringFromIndex:3]];
       break;

       case 10:
           formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-%@",
                          [formattedNumber substringToIndex:3],
                          [formattedNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 3)],
                          [formattedNumber substringFromIndex:6]];
       break;

       default:
           for (int i = 0; i < formattedNumber.length / substrSize; i++) {
           [t addObject:[formattedNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i * substrSize, substrSize)]];
           }
           if (formattedNumber.length % substrSize) {
               [t addObject:[formattedNumber substringFromIndex:(substrSize * t.count)]];
       }
           formattedNumber = [t componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
       break;
    }
    return formattedNumber;
   }
   ```

Comment: Nice code sample! Could you elaborate on what it does?

Answer (score 0):

In **SWIFT 3**

```
func formattedPhone(phone: String) -> String?  {
    let notPhoneNumbers = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
    let str = phone.components(separatedBy: notPhoneNumbers).joined(separator: "")

    let startIdx = str.startIndex
    let endIdx = str.endIndex

    let count = str.characters.count
    if count == 7 {
        return "\(str[startIdx..<startIdx.advance(3, for: str)])-\(str[startIdx.advance(3, for: str)..<endIdx])"
    }else if count == 10{
        return "+1 (\(str[startIdx..<startIdx.advance(3, for: str)])) \(str[startIdx.advance(3, for: str)..<startIdx.advance(6, for: str)])-\(str[startIdx.advance(6, for: str)..<endIdx])"
    }
    else if count > 10{
        let extra = str.characters.count - 10
        return "+\(str[startIdx..<startIdx.advance(extra, for: str)]) (\(str[endIdx.advance(-10, for: str)..<endIdx.advance(-7, for: str)])) \(str[endIdx.advance(-7, for: str)..<endIdx.advance(-4, for: str)])-\(str[endIdx.advance(-4, for: str)..<endIdx])"
    }
    return nil
}
```

Swift 3 string.index.advancedBy(3) alternate:

```
extension String.Index{
func advance(_ offset:Int, `for` string:String)->String.Index{
    return string.index(self, offsetBy: offset)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First,  add `UITextFieldDelegate` to your `.h` file and Delegate your `UITextField` in the `nib` file.

Second, add this code to your `.m` file :

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
        {
            NSString *filter = @"(###)-(###)-####";

            if(!filter) return YES;

            NSString *changedString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

            if(range.length == 1 && 
               string.length < range.length &&
               [[textField.text substringWithRange:range] rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"]].location == NSNotFound)
            {

                NSInteger location = changedString.length-1;
                if(location > 0)
                {
                    for(; location > 0; location--)
                    {
                        if(isdigit([changedString characterAtIndex:location]))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    changedString = [changedString substringToIndex:location];
                }
            }

            textField.text = [self filteredPhoneStringFromStringWithFilter:changedString :filter];

            return NO;

        }

    -(NSString*) filteredPhoneStringFromStringWithFilter:(NSString*)number : (NSString*)filter{
        NSUInteger onOriginal = 0, onFilter = 0, onOutput = 0;
        char outputString[([filter length])];
        BOOL done = NO;

    while(onFilter < [filter length] && !done)
    {
        char filterChar = [filter characterAtIndex:onFilter];
        char originalChar = onOriginal >= number.length ? '\0' : [number characterAtIndex:onOriginal];
        switch (filterChar) {
            case '#':
                if(originalChar=='\0')
                {
                    // We have no more input numbers for the filter.  We're done.
                    done = YES;
                    break;
                }
                if(isdigit(originalChar))
                {
                    outputString[onOutput] = originalChar;
                    onOriginal++;
                    onFilter++;
                    onOutput++;
                }
                else
                {
                    onOriginal++;
                }
                break;
            default:
                // Any other character will automatically be inserted for the user as they type (spaces, - etc..) or deleted as they delete if there are more numbers to come.
                outputString[onOutput] = filterChar;
                onOutput++;
                onFilter++;
                if(originalChar == filterChar)
                    onOriginal++;
                break;
        }
    }
    outputString[onOutput] = '\0'; // Cap the output string
    return [NSString stringWithUTF8String:outputString];
}
```