# How to Validation phone number and -

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

For the validation for the phone number and included -

@"^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$"

I have to validate phone number with -

example 333-333-3333 (Which is valid number).

how to customize the valid Regex with -  into phone number

Comment: Is your user going to be calling the phone number from this code? If so `#` and `*` are not allowed, they will be displayed but the phone will not initiate a call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IPhone simple phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180847/iphone-simple-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well it depends on how strict you want to be it doesn't seem like this regex is especially strict.
this regex says:

1. start at beginning of line
2. match one `+` (or maybe 1 or 0) which seems
   ambiguous (but may not be depending on implementation) because the
   capture parentheses:`()` breaks up the relationship of the `\+` and the `?`
3. possibly misplaced `:`
4. match any digit `0-9` 1 or 0 times 6-14 times
5. then one digit `0-9`
6. then end of line.

also you note that any backslash will have to be doubled... `@"\\b"` for a word boundary.
you may want to try something like...

```
@"\\b[\\d]{3}\\-[\\d]{3}\\-[\\d]{4}\\b"
would I think match your example, but it wouldn't match
(555) 555 - 5555 or
555.555.5555 or
+44 1865  55555
```

Comment: My Example is 555-555-5555  I can take number 0 to 9 or - symbol for the regular expression.

Comment: `[0-9]` doesn't mean `0 through 9` and the `-` symbol. something like `[0-9\-]` would

Comment: @ regular expresión if i go with [0-9\-]  its allow me 000-999-0999-  like this formate of entering number if i go with another format [0-9\@]  its will allow me 000@000@0000

Comment: @ Grady Player Thanks for the replay its really help my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Obj-C has NSPredicate for this. As I remember, you can use code like this for your task:

```
NSPredicate * Pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$'"];    
bool ifYes = [Pred evaluateWithObject:_yourNSString]];
```

for more detail look in Apple docs.

If you want to found proper reg.exp., please use some libs like: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7

Answer (score 1):

Both of the other answers will work, but they fail in significant ways:

1. They are not internationalized. They don't account for parentheses around the area code, or the country code, or spaces instead of hyphens.  All of these are valid permutations of phone numbers.
2. They're fragile.  What if someone doesn't want to enter an area code? What if something changes and all phone numbers in the US suddenly gain an extra digit? Will your code break?

The answer to this is to let the frameworks handle this for you.  There's a class called [`NSDataDetector`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on iOS 4+ and OS X 10.7+ that you can use for detecting physical addresses, email addresses, links, transit information, *phone numbers*, etc.

The documentation gives an example of how to use it.  This is a much better solution because it's code that you don't have to maintain.  It will work anywhere in the world.

Comment: I totally agree, but I don't really know NSDataDetector well, and don't want to speak to its capabilities. I do have one question to ask about it, and I know you are just the man to ask... is NSDataDetector locale aware? or will it match say a phone number from the UK when I have my locale set to en-US, the documentation doesn't really specify the class's assumptions or abilities very well. Does all of the power come from the NSTextCheckingResult?

Answer (score 0):

Just suggesting another way, as mentioned by @Dave DeLong as well NSDataDetector.
One of the best and elegant way provided by Apple.
Who might be looking for the implementation, here is the code snippet.

```
- (BOOL)applyPhoneValidation:(NSString*)theNumber
{
    NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber error:NULL];
    NSArray *matches = [detector matchesInString:theNumber options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, theNumber.length)];
    BOOL isValidNumber = (NSInteger)matches.count;
    return isValidNumber;
}
```

It will return 1 for the valid phone number.

Cheers
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

**//phone no format:(000)000-0000**

```
-(BOOL)numberValidation:(NSString*)phoneString
{

    NSString *phoneRegEx = @"\\([0-9]{3}\\)[0-9]{3}\\-[0-9]{4}";

    NSPredicate *phoneTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegEx];

    BOOL result=[phoneTest evaluateWithObject:phoneString];
   return result;

}
```