# Format textfield for CPF and CNPJ

Tags: ios, formatting

How should I handle text formatting in iOS? I'm not talking about Currency or Decimal styles. Since iOS doesn't have `setFormat()`, it's kind of complicated.

Two examples of the format I want: `123.456.789-10` and `123.456.789/1000-00`.

My aim is to format a text field as the user types. Like any normal site does when, for example, you type a phone number. It doesn't comes from a model or anything. The user just needs to type the numbers and when necessary I'll insert the `".","/"` or `"-"`.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what you are trying to do? How does the data in your model look, that ends up looking like the sample strings that you provided?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You're right! Edited the question.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Data Formatting Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/DataFormatting.html)? Have you [looked around on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+formatting+text+field)? The top hit from that search: [Phone number formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052966/phone-number-formatting).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes Josh! But as mentioned they were too extensive for just a simple text format plus, they all had some overhead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to do formatting, like this:

```
NSRegularExpression *fmt = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(.{1,3})(.{1,3})(.{1,3})(.{1,2})"
                         options:0
                           error:NULL];
NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"12345678910"];
[fmt replaceMatchesInString:str
                    options:0
                      range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)
               withTemplate:@"$1.$2.$3-$4"];
```

This transforms the string into `123.456.789-10`

In order to apply this formatting dynamically as users type, create `NSRegularExpression *fmt` upfront, store it in your `UITextFieldDelegate`, and use it in your `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method.

Comment: WOW!! That's what i'm talking about!! GREAT Answer!

Comment: @NSPunk Well, I have not tried using this for field formatting, so you may very well discover that it is not as performant as some simpler alternatives that do not rely on regular expressions. Anyway, give it a try, and let me know if it worked. If you are no longer looking for an improved answer, consider accepting one by clicking the outline of the check mark; this will earn you a brand-new badge on stack overflow, too.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own method a couple days ago for checking for valid temperature input.  It was a bit of a pain as well because I had to check for:
-only numbers
-only one decimal point
-if there was a negative sign it had to be at the front

I ended up using `[my string characterAtIndex:index];` and checking each character, since i would have no more than 4 characters.

EDIT:

Here is some pseudo code

```
for (every char in your string)
    if(the index of the char % 3 == 2) //every third char, 0,2,5...
        the char must be a . or / or -

    else
        the char must be a number
```

Comment: Yeah.. that is my initial thinking too, but it's really painful just to think about it!

Comment: yes you would need to make sure that every 3rd character is a decimal, dash, or slash, which would take a lot of if statements.  You may also be able to use `NSCharacterSets`, or if you know regular expressions (regex) you could use those.

Comment: Come to think of it, it wouldnt be too many if/else statements...  I've edited some psuedo code into my answer

Comment: That's a good point, but I'm doing something a little different. The user just need to type the numbers and i'll insert the special characters as needed by the format. So i believe it's more easier to do things!