# how to format textfield as you type on Java with Observable

Tags: java, android

I was looking for a way to achieve what's described here [Format textfield for CPF and CNPJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693724/format-textfield-for-cpf-and-cnpj) except for Android and the observable returned from EditText.  The following non-regex code *almost* gets me to where I need to be except for when I try to drop in the middle.

```
private String formatCpfAndPosition(String cpf) {
    int selectionStart = maskEditText.getSelectionStart();
    String formatted = cpf;
    if (inputCPFValidationListener != null) {
      int length = cpf.length();

      if ((length == 3 || length == 7 || length == 11)) {
        if (isDeleted(cpf)) {
          formatted = cpf.substring(0, length - 1);
          selectionStart -= 1;
        } else if (isLengthened(cpf)) {
          selectionStart += 1;
          if (length == 11) {
            formatted = formatted + "-";
          } else {
            formatted = formatted + ".";
          }
        }
      }
      lastCpf = formatted;
      maskEditText.setText(formatted);
      maskEditText.setSelection(selectionStart, selectionStart);
    }
    return formatted;
  }
```

I like the elegance offered by using regex but am unable to figure out how I'd use this.  Using `cpf.replaceAll("(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})", "$1.$2.$3-$4")` works *only* when the length of `cpf` reaches the 11 digit mark.  While my particular case is for Android use, I believe that this can be applicable to Java as a whole.

Comment: Why you don't use the regex from the answer you linked to? It works for 4+ digits.

Comment: @Oleg unfortunately, when I use the regex there, I get `1.2.3-4` instead of `123.4`, the latter being the preferred format.

Comment: What is your expected input and desired output?

Comment: examples of desired input and output are:
`123`  -> `123.`
`1234`  -> `123.4`
`123456` -> `123.456.`
`12345678901` -> `123.456.789-01`

Comment: Don't you also need to convert `123.45.7` to `123.457` for example(if a 6 is deleted)?