# Phone format according to country on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, locale

Is there any way to get phone number format according to country selected using Objective-C?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052966/phone-number-formatting

Comment: @bhuXan they are no duplicates. THe question you refer to formats accoding to US local. `world != US`

Comment: @RuneFS In SedateAlien's answer to the question mentioned by bhuXan, there's a link to a library that handles international phone numbers. So yes, it is kind of a duplicate.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I'll grant you that the answers is somewhat applicable in both cases. Logically that does not imply that the questions are the same. "Are you me?" and "Is the moon made of green cheese" is a contrieved example of two questions withe the same answer but the questions are obviously different. If I search for the answer to formatting according to country this and the linked to questions would be rather different from a SEO perspective

Answer (score 2):

Try using this library: https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS
It's an iOS port of Google's libphonenumber library used for parsing, formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers.
It has support for the folowing formats: national, international, E164, and RFC3966