# set appropriate key pad for phone number text field

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, uitextfield

In my iPhone app,there is a text field for entering phone number of user.I have tried number key pad,phone pad, decimal pad etc. But none is appropriate.

How to set a number key pad which contains the '-' key ?

Comment: Please try to use this one. I think you wanna it. You can use `Numbers and Punctuation` key pad

Answer (score 2):

You can add - yourself where you want to add like following code will add `brackets (`
 and `dash -` while entering numbers in textfield.

```
#pragma mark - Phone Number Field Formatting

// Adopted from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052966/phone-number-formatting
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == self.mobileNumberField) {
        int length = [self getLength:textField.text];
        if(length == 10) {
            if(range.length == 0)
                return NO;
        }
        if(length == 3) {
            NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) ",num];
            if(range.length > 0)
                textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[num substringToIndex:3]];
        }
        else if(length == 6) {
            NSString *num = [self formatNumber:textField.text];
            textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@-",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
            if(range.length > 0)
                textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@) %@",[num substringToIndex:3],[num substringFromIndex:3]];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

-(NSString*)formatNumber:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
    int length = [mobileNumber length];
    if(length > 10) {
        mobileNumber = [mobileNumber substringFromIndex: length-10];
    }
    return mobileNumber;
}


-(int)getLength:(NSString*)mobileNumber
{
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
    mobileNumber = [mobileNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
    int length = [mobileNumber length];
    return length;
}
```

[Taken from here](https://gist.github.com/gdavis/2845766)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the `UIKeyboardTypePhonePad` and use the `inputAccessoryView` property of `UITextField` for the `-` button.

#### Code:

```
UIToolbar *punctuationbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"-" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(addHyphen)],
                       nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
_yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = punctuationbar;
```

And add the `addHyphen` method like:

```
- (void)addHyphen
{
  _yourTextField.text = [_yourTextField.text stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
}
```

**Note:** This method will append `-` at the end of the text. You need to modify the above method.

---

#### Reference:

> **inputAccessoryView**
>
> The custom accessory view to display when the text field becomes the
>   first responder `@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView;`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The default value of this property is nil. Assigning a view to this
>   property causes that view to be displayed above the standard system
>   keyboard (or above the custom input view if one is provided) when the
>   text field becomes the first responder. For example, you could use
>   this property to attach a custom toolbar to the keyboard. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UITextField.h

Referece [UITextField Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)