# How can I apply this for a single text field?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: 
   (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{ }
```

I want this to only apply to the phone number field, whose tag is 1, so in this function I put

```
if(textField.tag != 1) { return NO; }
```

After I did this, I cannot even input anything into the other text fields. How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm formatting the phone number field using what was posted here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052966/phone-number-formatting and I don't want it to affect the password field

Comment: Make sure that your other textfields have different tag

Comment: The other field does have a different tag - the password field's tag is 2.

Comment: Instead of using that if to return NO, use `if (textField.tag == 1) {...)` and use the ... to format the phone number in that text field.

Comment: It's better to compare against a reference to the interesting textField, rather than using the tag.  Something like `if (textField == self.phoneField) ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do the formatting just for a specific text field (with tag=1):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: 
   (NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    if (textField.tag == 1) {
        // formatting here
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

If you return `NO` for other text fields, you explicitly state that changes are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I was close...was returning NO in the else statement originally