# Use NSNumberFormatterStyle to create a (US) phone number style

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to find a way to use NSNumberFormatter to format an input string of digits into a US phone number style.

For example: 
4155552671 should be +1-415-555-2671 (if i'm not mistaken)

I was wondering if theres an easy way to do this with native API (NSNumberFormatterStyle?), instead of using my own logic to modify the string.
any thoughts? 
Thanks.

Comment: `NSNumberFormatter` is not appropriate in any way for formatting phone numbers. Remember, a phone number isn't actually a number (in a math/computer sense). No numeric data type should ever be used to store a phone number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a suitable task for `NSNumberFormatter`.

Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052966/phone-number-formatting) can help.

There's also an [iOS ported version of Google's phone number library](https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS) which might help, you're probably looking for the RFC3966 output or a variation of the international one.