# Programmatically make phone call crash in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, openurl

Hello I am making a phone call programmatically. The phone number I am receiving from the back end is like 61234567890. It doesn't comes with the +. This is how I open the call.

```
self.openAppURL(strUrl: "tel://\(selectedEmployeeContact)")

func openAppURL(strUrl:String)
{
    let myurl=URL(string: strUrl)
    let isInstalled=UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(myurl!)
    if(isInstalled)
    {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(myurl!)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(myurl!)
        }
    }

}
```

I have a list of phone numbers. If number have 10 digits then it doesn't crash. but this number it crashing. Why its not handling by the `canOpenURL`. How to handle this properly.

Please help me.

Comment: were does it crash exactly?

Comment: can you add crash report

Comment: Can you add the exception's description?

Comment: Try this may it help you by format a number

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052966/phone-number-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `guard let` for prevent a crash.

```
    guard let number = URL(string: "tel://61234567890") else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(number)
```

This code is working fine more me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this prevented crashing :)

Comment: Happy to help you.