# Is it possible for UITextField to accept a pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, pattern-matching

I need the text field to show only certain characters that the user types. Besides, I want the text in the text field to be of certain pattern, for example, (###) ###-####, where # represents a digit. After the pattern is matched, the rest of what the user types will also be accepted. The pattern is not fixed, it can also be something like: ###/###-####. But I can provide the pattern. Is this possible?

Comment: definitely possible ! but some examples or sample i/o should be provided .

Comment: user can only fill **(###) ###-####** pattern (or other) in `textfield` or along with pattern they can write anything in the same `textfield` ??

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052966/phone-number-formatting

Comment: I will get a phone mask for the pattern. I do not know before-hand what it is. I think I need to separate the # characters (which are digits from 0 to 9) and non-# characters, and record the locations of the non-# characters. As the user types, I need to take account of how many #s have been entered and insert the non-# characters at the right locations. After the pattern is exhausted, whatever the user types will still be accepted. For example, for the pattern (###) ###-####, if the user types (123) 456-7890 ext. 123, it will be accepted. The link that Anbu.Karthik is definitely helpful.

Comment: What I said phone mask is basically the pattern I want the text field to show. It can be (###) ###-####, or ###-###-####, or ###/###-####, or any pattern that can be specified in another place, but not in the app.  In addition to iOS, I wonder if there is a similar method I can overwrite in Android? I also need to do the same thing in my Android app.